# Adding onclick function to an appended element in a loop via jquery

Tags: jquery, function, loops, onclick

Right now I'm passing the name of a function as a string to a jquery plugin that loops through a database creating a new element for each record, setting an onclick event for the element to the function name provided with data from the record as parameters for the function. This is appended to a string and is assigned to the innerhtml of a new div that is appended to the dom when the loop is finished. Originally I was appending to the dom each time, but this was horribly slow.

What I'd like to do is pass the function itself to the plugin, or an anonymous function if the user desires. But due to my building the div as a string, I'm unsure the best way to associate the passed function with each element's onclick event.

Comment: Either (a) don't use a string and build up the DOM elements yourself, then insert them all in one go or (b) write the `onclick` attribute into the string and refer to a global callback function. You may want to post your code if you want more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe use the live function in jquery http://api.jquery.com/live/

Set a class for your div, so it would give something like that :

```
$(".myDiv").live("click", function(){//my function});
```

All that it is if it's the same function for all div